# String search across a column

Tags: vim

I want to search for a string which is written in column. Is there a way to search for this using vim? For example:

```
B
A
S
I
C
```

If i wanted to search for the word BASIC column wise, how could I do it in vim?

Comment: transform the buffer rows to columns, then search, return the TarnsformedColNo as rowNo, TransformedRowNo as colNo.

Answer (score 0):

#### via regular expression

Regular expressions (which power Vim's search) can only express consecutive character matches. Therefore, you can only match the text starting with the `B` and ending with `C`, including all text in between:

```
/B.*\n.*A.*\n.*S.*\n.*I.*\n.*C
```

By using `.*\n.*`, this asserts that each character is in a following line. Another shortcoming of regular expressions is that you cannot assert a match at the same column, so above would also match a non-aligned `BASIC`. You can only avoid that for a fixed column with the special `\%v` atom:

```
/\%32vB.*\n.*\%32vA.*\n.*\%32vS.*\n.*\%32vI.*\n.*\%32vC
```

#### via blockwise visual selection

Vim does have one way to select a vertical block of characters in visual mode `<C-v>`. Using Vimscript (e.g. `getline()` or `searchpos()`), you could search for the individual characters and then build such a selection.

#### via text transformation

As Kent commented, if you transform the text (effectively a 90° counter-clockwise rotation), you can then easily match the (now horizontal) text via the default search.

Comment: How would you go about transforming the text?

Comment: @Ben: That's hard to answer in a comment, but a naive attempt would be via a two-dimensional intermediate array.